# How to get/set input fields from multiple html from same external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, return-value, fetch, input-field

I have two html files, A.html and B.html, and one external java script file called C.js
When I run A.html, I want to read value of input filed of B.html from Java script but it's not reading value of input field. It just returns null.
B.html looks like this (I am showing only form)

```html
<form action="" name="form1" id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value="Hello">
</form>
```

I have this code in Java script (C.js) which is called by A.html successfully.

```js
function readInputText(){
    var myVal = document.getElementById("text1").value;     
    // Above line is not working. I tried document.form1.text1.value also but did not work.
}
```

Did I miss anything that prevented Java script code from reading the text value from A.html?

Comment: _“When I run A.html, I want to read value of input filed of B.html”_ – first of all, you don’t “run” HTML documents, you just make your browser _display_ them. And to be able to ”read” a value from an input field in the second file, your browser must be displaying this at the same time, in another window instance that the first document has access to. (Unless you want to actually read the code content of the whole file and parse it yourself, but I assume that is not what you want.)

Comment: How is B.html being displayed on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change".value" to ".innerHTML"